# How to `strftime` having timezone adjusted?

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

I store my datetime int UTC like so:

```
import pytz, datetime

timeUTC = datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 23, 19, 27, 50, 0)
timezoneLocal = pytz.timezone('Europe/Vilnius')

timeLocal = timezoneLocal.localize(timeUTC)
```

But when I try to print it, it just gives me regular UTC hours

```
>>> timeLocal.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'19:27:50'
```

I would expect this to return `'22:27:50'` since this is the local time (`pytz.timezone('Europe/Vilnius')` is +3 at the moment). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Localize the date string as a UTC datetime, then use `astimezone` to convert it to the local timezone.

```
import pytz, datetime

timeUTC = datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 23, 19, 27, 50, 0)
timezoneLocal = pytz.timezone('Europe/Vilnius')
utc = pytz.utc
timeLocal = utc.localize(timeUTC).astimezone(timezoneLocal)
print(timeLocal)
# 2013-05-23 22:27:50+03:00
```

`localize` does not *convert* datetimes, it interprets the date string as though it were written in that timezone. `localize` builds a timezone-aware datetime out of a naive datetime (such as `timeUTC`). `astimezone` converts timezone-aware datetimes to other timezones.

Comment: that worked like a charm (although I'm not sure that it's as intuitive as it could be...), thanks!