# unable to display time in different timezone

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

When I change `tzinfo` on an aware `datetime` instance I keep getting the same `strftime` result:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> fmt = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'
>>> now_naive = datetime.utcnow()
>>> now_naive.strftime(fmt)
'02.08.2017 11:53'

>>> now_aware = now_naive.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
>>> now_aware_minus_3 = now_aware.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT-3'))
>>> now_aware.strftime(fmt)
'02.08.2017 11:53'

>>> now_aware_minus_3.strftime(fmt)
'02.08.2017 11:53'
```

Why is that? how do I display current time in different timezone?

Comment: Isn't this a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008960/pytz-and-etc-gmt-5)?

Comment: This may help. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18646797/5585424

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \`strftime\` having timezone adjusted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722464/how-to-strftime-having-timezone-adjusted)

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way :

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

x=datetime.now(timezone('Europe/Madrid'))
print x
x=datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
print x
x=datetime.now(timezone('Etc/GMT-3'))
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.replace(tzinfo=...)` only replaces the timezone in the datetime object, without performing an actual timezone conversion.

Try this instead:

```
time_unaware = datetime.utcnow()
time_utc = pytz.timezone('UTC').localize(time_unaware)  # same as .replace(tzinfo=...)
time_gmt_minus_3 = time_utc.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT-3'))  # performs timezone conversion
```

Using `.strftime()` on `time_gmt_minus_3` should now show what you expected.

Also, @sophros has linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008960/pytz-and-etc-gmt-5):

> In order to conform with the POSIX style, those zones beginning with "Etc/GMT" have their sign reversed from what most people expect. In this style, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a negative sign.